# AppCompatButton and Color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I am designing a game and need to make my app compatible back to API 16. I found how to do the AppCompatButton and set the style but how do I change the color to a more pleasing color like a light blue?

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="Button"/>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you'll go into `AppCompatButton` class you'll see there this javadoc:

```
<ul>
    <li>Supports {@link R.attr#textAllCaps} style attribute which works back to
    {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#GINGERBREAD Gingerbread}.</li>
    <li>Allows dynamic tint of it background via the background tint methods in
    {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat}.</li>
    <li>Allows setting of the background tint using {@link R.attr#backgroundTint} and
    {@link R.attr#backgroundTintMode}.</li>
</ul>
```

So you can set `backgroundTint` attribute to tour button in XML file. Like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:lines="2"
    android:text="Button"
    app:backgroundTint="#555000"/>     <-- Here
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:background` attribute to your button declaration with value referring to the colour resource

```
android:background="@color/button_color"
```

Or specifying color

```
android:background="#000000"
```

Comment: If you'll set background to color - you'll lose all state (`state_pressed`, `state_enabled` and so on) and ripple effects (on 21+) that is provided in button by default.

Answer (score 0):

Define a style like this:

```
<!-- put this in res/values/styles.xml -->
<style name="StyledButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_background</item>
</style>
```

Apply to the button as usual:

```
<!-- apply style to button -->
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/StyledButton"/>
```

This should be compatible with all the API levels.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I needed to set the colorAccent in the colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I needed to define the colorAccent:

```
     <color name="colorAccent">#448AFF</color>
```